# How does degree theory imply that this mapping $f$ is locally onto?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth vector field ($\mathcal{C}^1$ mapping). Let $0$ be a [critical point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_%28mathematics%29) of $f$, i.e. $H f(0) = 0$.

Assume that the [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28mathematics%29#Analysis) of $f$ at $0$ is positive: $\text{ind}(f,0) >0$.

Please explain the following statement (I've found on a paper):

> "From Degree Theory, the mapping $f$ is locally onto."

Is this implied by the [Browder-Minty Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browder%E2%80%93Minty_theorem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest that you find yourself a copy of *Topology from the differentiable viewpoint* by J. Milnor. There you will find all the relevant definitions.

Briefly, the index $\mathrm{ind}(f,0)$ of a vectorfield $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ around a fixed point $f(0)=0$ such that $f$ vanishes only in $0$, is the topological degree of the map
$$g_r(x)=\frac{f(x)}{\|f(x)\|}$$
$g_r:S_r\to\mathbb{S}^n$, where $S_r=\{x\ :\ \|x\|=r\}$. The degree of the map $g_r$ is constant for small values of $r$.

By degree theory, the degree is an homotopy invariant and a non-surjective map is homotopic to a constant (which has degree $0$), thereofre a map with positive degree has to be surjective, so every $g_r$ is surjective. This means that $f(S_r)$ surrounds $0$ for every $r$ small enough, meaning that $0$ is in the bounded component of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus f(S_r)$. (remember that $0$ was an isolated critical point, therefore $f$ is a local embedding outside $0$).

$r\mapsto f(S_r)$ is continuous and $\mathrm{dist}(0, f(S_r))\to0$ when $r\to0$, therefore if there were a sequence of points staying outside of the range of $f$ on every ball surrounding $0$, this sequence would have to pass from the *inside* of $f(S_r)$ to the outside of some other $f(S_\rho)$, with a continuous motion, without being on the boundary of any $f(S_s)$ with $\rho\leq s\leq r$ (otherwise it would be in the range of $f$). But this is absurd.

Therefore $f$ is surjective.

**NB:** Probably there are shorter ways of proving this, but this is, I think, the most *visual* one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it is not clear to me. First, why should we consider $y \mapsto \text{ind}(f,y)$ since we fix the critical point to be $0$? Second, I am not clear with "$y$ belonging to the range of $f$", because, again, $y=0$ is fixed and we look at the range of $f$. By the way, from which result/statement does your implication "if $f$ doesn't belong to..., then ..." follow? What is the "intersection number"? Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: Maybe you should give me the definition you know of index of a function at a point, then i will be able to answer in a more suitable way.

Comment: According to my Note, I think that the Index of a mapping at a Critical Point is the Winding Number of a small counterclockwise oriented circle with center at the critical point."

Comment: Is this somehow referring to the Generalized Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: Maybe you mean the winding number of an image of that circle around the image of the critical point? (which happens to be the point as it is fixed) But, anyhow, in $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is no such thing, unless $n=2$, because $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})=0$ if $n\geq 3$. So, are you considering only the plane?

Comment: I took this definition of index from http://jdc.math.uwo.ca/M9052-2011/vector-fields.pdf

Comment: That's about *planar* vector-fields, not maps between euclidean spaces...  Here you are concerned with maps between higher dimensional spaces... I will rewrite my answer, giving some definitions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So my understanding was wrong. I care about the high-dimensinal case, not the planar one.

Comment: Anyway, I still do not get why we look into the map $y \mapsto \text{ind}(f,y)$ since the critical point is $0$.

Comment: Moreover, the initial sentence "if $y$ does not belong to the range of $f$ then $\text{ind}(f,y) = 0$" seems to be the statement we have to prove, right? In fact, we basically have to prove that $\text{ind}(f,0) \neq 0 \Longrightarrow y \in \text{range}(f)$ for all $y$ in a neighborhood of $0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: I have edited my answer to better answer your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small answer! If $f$ is not onto, then $\exists y_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $f^{-1}(y_0)=\varnothing$ and therefore $\mathrm{deg}(f,y_0)=0$. Since $y\mapsto\mathrm{deg}(f,y_0)$ is locally constant and $\mathbb{R}^n$ connected, then the degree of $f$ is identically zero. $\mathrm{deg}(f,y)=0$, $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.